# Can we use Apache Kafka that is dockerized in production?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, containers

I was wondering what would be the pros and cons of using docker for a streaming platform like Apache Kafka. Can this set up be used in production ?

I'm learning a bit of kafka and docker, newbie to both so keep calm and try to solve my doubt :)

Answer (score 2):

We're using Kafka on docker in a production environment for almost 2 years now. We have three node zookeeper, 3 node Kafka and a single schema-registry (maybe scale up later). So far we haven't faced any issues. Assuming you provide enough storage space to the Kafka data directory (in volume mounts), after calculating the ingestion rate and retention policy, I don't foresee any problem.